# How can I find the source code of builtin zsh widgets (zle)?

Tags: zsh

Where are builtin zle widgets stored? I am trying to find the code for `beginning-of-buffer-or-history` and `beginning-of-line`. `zle -al` output shows these exist in my machine.

I have ran:

```
% echo $widgets[beginning-of-buffer-or-history]
user:_zsh_autosuggest_bound_1_beginning-of-buffer-or-history
% echo $widgets[beginning-of-line]
user:_zsh_autosuggest_bound_1_beginning-of-line
```

Could not find out where the widgets are located.

Comment: These are C functions compiled into the `zsh` executable. Is your question about how these are implemented? See e.g. https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/Zle/zle_hist.c#L561

Comment: You may possibly want to update your question with the underlying issue that you are trying to resolve.

Comment: @Kusalananda Here is the details of the question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/747715/206574

Comment: So your new question supersedes this one?

Comment: @Kusalananda I got the answer of this question in the comment.

Comment: That was a comment where I was asking for clarification.

Comment: I thought `beginning-of-buffer-or-history` and `beginning-of-line` was zle widgets, which I can go through and copy paste code. But these are C codes. I will not use these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets you mention are not `zsh` shell functions but internally implemented ZLE widgets, implemented as C functions in the `zsh` executable.

- The `beginning-of-buffer-or-history` widget [is bound to](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/88eeade0bcdba8beb4a94534312b8febbc608697/Src/Zle/iwidgets.list#L27) the function [`beginningofbufferorhistory`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/88eeade0bcdba8beb4a94534312b8febbc608697/Src/Zle/zle_hist.c#L561).
- The `beginning-of-line` widget [is bound to](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/88eeade0bcdba8beb4a94534312b8febbc608697/Src/Zle/iwidgets.list#L29) the function [`beginningofline`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/88eeade0bcdba8beb4a94534312b8febbc608697/Src/Zle/zle_move.c#L298).

Comment: In the OP's case, those widgets have been redefined / overloaded though, and if the corresponding function has been loaded (or `-r`/`-R` was passed to `autoload` for it), `type _zsh_autosuggest_bound_1_beginning-of-buffer-or-history` will tell you where their definition is.