# How to select the whole buffer by using zle widget?

Tags: zsh

I have a zle widget like:

```
_ctrl-a() {
  CURSOR=0
  if ((MARK == 0)); then
    zle set-mark-command
  fi

  if [ "$BUFFERLINES" -gt 1 ]; then
    zle end-of-buffer-or-history
  else
    zle end-of-line
  fi
}

zle -N _ctrl-a
bindkey '^A' _ctrl-a # Ctrl+A
```

It selects the whole buffer. I mean it put cursor at the beginning of the buffer, start marking then put the cursor at the end of buffer.

Here, the widget I am using for multi-line command is `end-of-buffer-or-history`, however, I want it to be `end-of-buffer`.

So, I want to replace:

```
if [ "$BUFFERLINES" -gt 1 ]; then
  zle end-of-buffer-or-history
else
  zle end-of-line
fi
```

with

```
zle end-of-buffer
```

But there seems to be no widget for `end-of-buffer`.

What can I do?

**P.S.** It would be a good learning experience if I could select the whole buffer using `MARK` variable.

Comment: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/edit-command-line select the whole buffer and open it in editor. The code looks like this is what i want. But not understanding how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [widget code](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#User_002dDefined-Widgets), you can not only read but also modify variables like `MARK`, `CURSOR`, `BUFFER`, etc.

To move the cursor to the end of the buffer:

```
CURSOR=$#BUFFER
```

To select the whole buffer with the mark at the beginning and the cursor at the end, you don't need to call any widget: just set the appropriate variables.

```
function _ctrl-a {
  MARK=0
  CURSOR=$#BUFFER
  REGION_ACTIVE=1
}
```

Comment: If i replace `REGION_ACTIVE=1` with `zle exchange-point-and-mark` only then it works.

Comment: The lines that work for me are `((CURSOR = 0)); ((MARK = $#BUFFER)); zle exchange-point-and-mark`

Comment: @AhmadIsmail The code I posted works with `zsh -f`, in any of emacs/viins/vicmd, with zsh 5.8.1. There may be configurations that could break that code, but I can't think of any.

Comment: The code you provided misses first word in every line. https://pasteboard.co/TvzMxjbhFzJ9.png I know it should not happen, but it is happening. I am using zsh 5.8 . This does not happen when i use the code which i have provided above. I do not know the explanation.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail That's presumably due to some setting in your `.zshrc`, but I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Due to https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting if i disable this plugin then your code works.